# SharePoint Diagnostic Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0?

Tags: diagnostics

I want to use the [SharePoint Diagnostic Studio 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144782.aspx#issues) in my dev. environment. But everytime I get the following error:

```
Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.237 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.
```

I installed also the .Net Framework 4.0 in this environment.
How can I fix this problem? (Without uninstall .Net 4.0 ;-) )

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure about this one ,

But I always go

SharePoint 2010
Diagnostic
Then .net 4
Then VS2010 when we build VMs for our Dev's assuming u need .net 4 for VS2010.

Looking at uninstalling .net 4 check here http://wellytonian.com/2011/07/quick-uninstallation-of-net-4/

Command line - clean and quiet uninstall.

U dont have to uninstall VS2010. Just take off .net do the Diagnostic install then put .net back in again.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is built on .Net framework 3.5. So you face this issue.